# Using iOS Static Library built with older SDK

Tags: ios, static-libraries

Can we link iOS Static Library built with older SDK with an app that is built with newer iOS SDK ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What keeps you from starting a new blank Xcode project, adding a static library in question and testing it out for yourself?

Comment: I can and it might work also. But wanted some confirmation because crashes are some times random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes..you can link static library built with older SDK **only when** this library use iOS api which are not outdated. **But in case if this library use depricated iOS API**, according to Apple, "A method identified as deprecated has been superseded and may become unsupported in the future." Therefore chances are your app will gets crash on access of outdated api of iOS.